# Infinite Loop in Nested Function MIPS Code

Tags: mips

I am having issues with this segment of MIPS code. 
It is causing an infinite loop and causing my simulation to crash. 
The object of the code is to create a nested function to find the sum of the first n squares. For example: if you enter 4, you would get 30 as the result.

I believe the infinite loop is occurring the first function call (sumSquares). The function `squares` has been tested independently so I am confident that it works.

I was hoping someone could help me!

```
.data
    prompt:  .asciiz "Number to square: "
    prompt2: .asciiz "Number of squares to sum: "
    return:  .asciiz "Square: "
    return2: .asciiz "Sum of the first n sqaures"
    test:       .asciiz "Testing location"
.text
.globl main

main: 
    # Print the string asking of "Number of squares to sum: "
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt2
    syscall

    # capture user input
    li $v0, 5
    syscall

    # store the value in a register
    move $s0, $v0
    move $a0, $s0

    # store the function 'square' is $ra
    jal sumSquare

    # Exit
    li $v0, 10
    syscall

sumSquare:
    # allocate space on the stack 
    addi $sp $sp, -8
    sw   $ra, 4($sp)
    sw   $a1, 0($sp)

    # store the passed in argument in a register
    move $t3, $a0           # store user's input

    # initialize temp registers to be used
    add $t4, $t4, $0        # $t4 is used to store the sum
    add $t5, $t5, $0        # $t5 = 0; used for counter

    Loop2: beq $t5, $t3, Exit2
        move $a1, $t3
        jal  square
        add  $t4, $t4, $v0
        addi $t5, $t5, 1
        j Loop2

    Exit2:
    # Print the string asking of "Number of squares to sum: "
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t4
    syscall

    # transfer control back to the caller -> main
    jr $ra

square:
    # store the passed in argument in a register
    move $t0, $a1           # store user's input

    # initialize variables to use in the loop
    add $t1, $t1, $0        # $t1 is used to store the sum
    add $t2, $t2, $t0       # $t2 = $t0; used for counter

    Loop: beq $t2, $0, Exit
        add  $t1, $t1, $t0
        addi $t2, $t2, -1
        j Loop
    Exit:

    # print the value back out
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t1
    syscall

    # restore 
    lw $s0, 4($sp)
    lw $ra, 8($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 12


    # transfer control back to the caller  -> sumSquares
jr $ra
```

Comment: `sumSquare` is never restoring the registers it saved on the stack upon entry.

Comment: Am I not doing that by having the line `jr $ra`. I do no understand

Comment: As you can see in _MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set_, the only thing `jr $ra` does is jump to the address contained in `$ra`.

Comment: I have tried to implement what you have said in the following lines that occurs in the square function:  
 `lw $s0, 4($sp)
 lw $ra, 8($sp)
        addi $sp, $sp, 12` This is right before the `jr $ra`.

Comment: Well, 1) You added the code to the wrong function (`square` instead of `sumSquare`), and 2) The code you added does not correspond to how you saved the registers when entering `sumSquare` (it uses different registers and offsets).

Answer (score 0):

jr $ra is not changing the values of the the register so it is never returning to the main and hence is going in the infinite loop. Instead use syscall function to terminate.

```
.data
    prompt:  .asciiz "Number to square: "
    prompt2: .asciiz "Number of squares to sum: "
    return:  .asciiz "Square: "
    return2: .asciiz "Sum of the first n sqaures"
    test:       .asciiz "Testing location"
.text
.globl main

main: 
    # Print the string asking of "Number of squares to sum: "
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt2
    syscall

    # capture user input
    li $v0, 5
    syscall

    # store the value in a register
    move $s0, $v0
    move $a0, $s0

    # store the function 'square' is $ra
    jal sumSquare

    # Exit
    li $v0, 10
    syscall

sumSquare:
    # allocate space on the stack 
    addi $sp $sp, -8
    sw   $ra, 4($sp)
    sw   $a1, 0($sp)

    # store the passed in argument in a register
    move $t3, $a0           # store user's input

    # initialize temp registers to be used
    add $t4, $t4, $0        # $t4 is used to store the sum
    add $t5, $t5, $0        # $t5 = 0; used for counter

    Loop2: beq $t5, $t3, Exit2
        move $a1, $t3
        jal  square
        add  $t4, $t4, $v0
        addi $t5, $t5, 1
        j Loop2

    Exit2:
    # Print the string asking of "Number of squares to sum: "
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t4
    syscall

    
   
li $v0, 10 # terminate
syscall 

square:
    # store the passed in argument in a register
    move $t0, $a1           # store user's input

    # initialize variables to use in the loop
    add $t1, $t1, $0        # $t1 is used to store the sum
    add $t2, $t2, $t0       # $t2 = $t0; used for counter

    Loop: beq $t2, $0, Exit
        add  $t1, $t1, $t0
        addi $t2, $t2, -1
        j Loop
    Exit:

    # print the value back out
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t1
    syscall

    # restore 
    lw $s0, 4($sp)
    lw $ra, 8($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 12


   

li $v0, 10 # terminate
syscall
```